# Trying to get data from service into component.ts

Tags: angular, angular7, angular-services

I am trying to just get data from the service and put it into my component.ts file. I have the service subscribe to the http get and it returns the data but after i try to get the data in the component. I just don't know how to go about it not trying to get the data until its done doing the call in the service.

I'm not sure if I'm just doing the pipe wrong or if i should be subscribing. Nothing I've looked up is really helping.

In the console I get the pipe error and then after the error it outputs the observable from the service.

My SearchService.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";
import { Row } from "../../app/row";
import { Observable } from "rxjs";
import { of } from "rxjs";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SearchServiceService {

  players: Observable<Row[]>;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getPlayers(searchTerm: String): Observable<Row[]>{
    let ROOT_URL =
    "http://lookup-service-prod.mlb.com/json/named.search_player_all.bam?sport_code='mlb'&active_sw='Y'&name_part='" +
   searchTerm +
    "%25'";
    this.http.get<Row[]>(ROOT_URL).subscribe(data => {
      let res = data["search_player_all"];
      let query = res["queryResults"];
      let row = query["row"];
      if (row != null) {
        this.players = row;
        console.log(this.players);
        return this.players;
      }
    });
    return this.players;
  }
}
```

AppComponent.ts

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
import { Row } from "../app/row";
import { Observable } from "rxjs";
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { SearchServiceService } from "../app/services/search-service.service"

@Component({
  selector: "app-root",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.scss"]
})
export class AppComponent {
  players: Row[];
  value = "";
  buttonClicked = false;
  numReturned = -1;
  searchTerm = "";
  constructor(private searchService: SearchServiceService) {}

  getData() {
    if (this.value != "") {
      this.searchTerm = this.value;

      this.searchService.getPlayers(this.searchTerm).pipe(map(data => {
        if(data == null) {
          console.log('IS NULL');
        }
        else {
          console.log('in service');
          this.players = data;
          console.log(this.players);
          this.buttonClicked = true;
        }
      }));

      if(this.players == null) {
        console.log('null');
        this.numReturned = -1;
      }

    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to return just the http.get like this:

```
getPlayers(searchTerm: String): Observable<Row[]>{
    return this.http.get<Row[]>(ROOT_URL);
}
```

Also in your code this.players is not an Observable it is a plain data that your api returned.

So instead of this:

```
this.searchService.getPlayers(this.searchTerm).pipe(map(
```

Just subscribe:

```
this.searchService.getPlayers(this.searchTerm).subscribe((data: any) => { <process your data here> });
```

Comment: it can't work, in the component he isn't subscribing to the obs$ so the http call will never fire

Comment: @FrancescoFortin Yes, that's true. So in "this.searchService.getPlayers().subscribe() also must be called. I updated my answer.

Comment: The call goes off the way I have I put a console.log before the return this,players outside of the http get and that returns first and then the http returns after that

Comment: @joe_monaco98 you need to assign `this.players = data;  this.buttonClicked = true;` inside the subscribe block

Comment: @joe_monaco98 as robert mentioned you need to return `this.http.get<Row[]>(ROOT_URL)` only from your service, Your subscribe should be in component.

Comment: Okay thank you. My thinking was that the logic of what I had to do with the returned data should stay in the service but that makes more sense since Im just getting data from the service and manipulating it in the controller. Thank you.